# make_sock: could not bind to address (IPv6) after network driver update

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-7

For some reason on CAT 6E cable I'm capped at 100 megabits (the ISP has a downstream of 400). I updated my network driver. Immediately afterwards when launching Apache I receive the following error (on the command line):

> (OS 10049)The requested address is not valid in its context.  :
>   AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
>
> [fe70::7ddce:a0b21:5976:b83d]:80 AH00451: no listening sockets
>   available, shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs

- I came across someone's post who tried `httpd -t` to check the syntax and Apache returns that the syntax is `OK`.
- Changing the port number in `httpd.conf` does not effect the error message.
- Nothing is running on port 80 (Resource Monitor).

The only other thing I've tried is disabling IPv6 on the network adapter though that had no effect. I'm not sure what I should do next though?

Comment: The CAT6E detail mean nothing, as your ISP control the modem, are you sure it's set to 400 ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 Resolved issue. In regards to your comment we tested about 360 megabits directly (I was stuck at 2 this past summer so I can live with 100) though knowing how to solve problems is always useful. There are no networking issues at the switch and my friend says the port should do a gigabit.

Comment: Im glad your issue is solved, my comment was more meant that cat5e support giga too, honestly a lot of other factor can kick in to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @yagmoth555 True - I'm now attempting to resolve *that* issue here: https://superuser.com/questions/1372027/cat-6e-only-getting-100-megabits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `httpd.conf` apparently the file was configured to listen to an IPv6 IP on port 80. I believe I may have set this and attempted to connect to a local IPv6 IP address at some point in the past. I'm not sure why updating the network adapter's driver would effect the Apache configuration.

```
Listen 80
Listen [fe70::7ddce:a0b21:5976:b83d]:80
```

Deleting the second line (or putting a `#` as the first character to comment it out) resolved the issue.

It seems Apache should still start and throw some sort of warning flag if one of the listen options isn't working though at least one is.

Comment: Try `Listen [::]:80` instead.